# don't recursively check imported typescript files

Tags: typescript

I want to just check javascript files given by some explicit filter. That would be a glob include or just purely a list of files. How can I achieve this? Currently, when I try to check a javascript files with command like this:

```
node_modules/.bin/tsc --noEmit --allowJs src/myFile.js
```

it will start to report errors from imported files. I just want to error reports from the file `src/myFile.js`, if it imports something, just consider it to be of `any` type and don't typecheck/report anything from it.

I want to ignore all imported things, whenever I do `import abc from "./xxx.js"` and then I'm using the `abc`, I want the compiler to thing that `abc` is of any type and ignore the "./xxx.js" file

Comment: ok I clarified the question